# size, length and count in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > u = User.find_by_email("email@mail.ru")
1.9.3p194 :005 > u.addresses.size
 => 1 
1.9.3p194 :006 > u.addresses.length
 => 1 
1.9.3p194 :007 > u.addresses.count
```

There is no difference between size, length and count in Rails 3.2.3, isn't it?

Comment: tip: if you want all emails with a particualar search use `find_all_by` eg ` User.find_all_by_email("email@mail.ru")`
 User.find_by_email("email@mail.ru") just returns first matched record

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**length** will load all your objects just to count them; something like:

```
select * from addresses...
```

and then return the results count.
As you can imagine - it's bad performance

**count** will just issue

```
select count(*) from addresses...
```

which is better, because we are not loading all addresses just to count them

**size** is smarter - it'll check if the association is already loaded and if true then return the length (without issuing a call to the database).

**size** also checks for **counter_cache** if you have a field named **address_count** in your user model, then size will use this field for the count, so there is no need to issue a count on the addresses table.

if all fails, **size** will issue a `select count(*)` on the database

Comment: length is often the best option.   If you're planning on doing something with the records after checking the record count, then using `size` may result in two database trips whereas `length` would only result in one.

Answer (score 4):

1) In rails count is a ActiveRecord method, therefore count can be applied on    model name directly as:

```
> User.count
   (1.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
=> 1
```

But size is not ActiveRecord method therefore it will throw an error

```
> User.size
"NoMethodError".
```

2) Size in rails can be used with ActiveRecord array (ie. size is Array method)

```
> User.all.size
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
=> 1
```

3) count will always fire ActiveRecord query. but size will not fire ActiveRecord query, only if record or ActiveRecord array is already loaded (executed) as:

```
  > d=User.all
  User Load (18.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, email: "fasf@f.df", name: "mano", dob: "2017-02-16", address: "fasfafasf", created_at: "2017-02-12 08:16:12", updated_at: "2017-02-12 09:34:07", online: false>]> 
2.3.3 :009 > 
2.3.3 :010 >   d.count
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
 => 1 
2.3.3 :011 > d.size
 => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If "addresses" is an association which it looks like, then they are different but they should return the same result.

#count is provided by ActiveRecord and will execute something like "select count(*) from addresses where user_id = ".

In the other cases, #addresses will build an array containing actual model objects and #size and #length are provided by the Array class or maybe Enumerable.

So #count is probably faster, because the counting happens in the database.  Not much good if you actually need the addresses tho :)

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't think about associations.