# Ruby on Rail - Check if at least 2 records with my condition exsist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

In my application, I want to show db records **only** if 2 records with my/same conditions exists?

What is the most efficient way of checking it?

*Here is my code:*

```
- if @users.where(friend_group: 0).where(city_id: 2).any?
  - @users.where(user_group: 0).where(city_id: 2).each do |user|
    %p= user.name
    %p= user.city.name
```

Instead of `any?`, I want to check if when **only** 2 records with same conditions exist, it can show them.

I have tried `- if @users.where(friend_group: 0).where(city_id: 2).exist?(2)`, with no luck.

*ps: I am using rails 4.2*

Comment: Exactly two or at least two? If at least two, do you want to show all records or only two of them (which, by what order)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use active record relation's `#count`, and range indexation as follows:

```
- rela = @users.where(friend_group: 0).where(city_id: 2)
- if rela.count > 1
  - rela[0..1].each do |user|
    %p= user.name
    %p= user.city.name
```

Comment: With most RDBMS, if you have  a very long list of users in a very large table, you don't need the exact count to only know that there's more than 1. You can simply count the first 2: `@users.where(friend_group: 0).where(city_id: 2).limit(2).count == 2` is a lot more performant and gives you what you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should avoid doing database queries in the view - A better solution is to do it in the controller or in the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def self.by_group_and_city(friend_group, city, threshold: 2)
    scope = User.where(friend_group: friend_group, city: city)
    # if you want only if exactly two records match then use ==
    scope.size >= threshold ? scope : User.none
  end
end
```

We return `User.none` instead of nil if there are no matching records - that way you can safely call methods like `.each` on the empty relation object.

```
- User.by_group_and_city(0, 2).each do |u|
  %p= user.name
  %p= user.city.name
```

Better yet would be let the controller do the querying:

```
def index
  @nearby_users = User.by_group_and_city(0, 2)
  # ...
end
```

---

```
- @nearby_users.each do |u|
  %p= user.name
  %p= user.city.name
```

Comment: I suggest to use `length` or `size` in this context instead of `count`, because using `count` will make a second database query when the `threshold` is met. Whereas `length` would load the relation and therefore no second query would be fired. Read about the differences between [`length`, `size` and `count`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12257642/2483313)

Comment: Good point @spickermann, I changed it to size and then its up to the OP to select what strategy to use - preloading the models before counting can be faster in some cases but sometimes a COUNT query + a regular select is faster.

Comment: @max Thanks, Good solution but it didn't suite my needs, but I learned much from it :)