# Rails: how to query the length of a has_many relationship while caching it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given the following model:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end
```

If I run

```
author.books.any?
```

I hit the database with an `EXISTS` query. If I run

```
1000.times { author.books.any? }
```

the result is 1000 queries, because the result is not cached in-memory on the `author` object.

I'm in a real-life situation similar to the above, where I'm calling (a method that uses) `author.books.any?` thousands of times on the same `author` object.

I want to avoid the excess queries by caching the result on the author object. What is the most expressive way to do this? I know e.g. `author.books.to_a.any?` will work, but it is not semantic. (It also caches all the associated data instead of just the associated data's length, but that is OK with me because in my case the associated table is very small.)

Is there a built-in alternative to `any?` or `exists?` on `ActiveRecord::Relation` that does what I want?

Comment: You can create query, that will fetch authors whose books.count > 0

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly known as a N+1 query issue.

If you eager load the assocation with `includes` or `eager_load` it will not create a count or exists query:

```
author = Author.includes(:books).first
author.books.any?
```

This is because `any?` uses `.size` which is smart enough to tell that the association has been loaded. It can thus use `.length` on the collection instead of querying the database.

[size, length and count in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253277/size-length-and-count-in-rails)

If you often need the count of an association without joining you can define a counter-cache on the model.

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, counter_cache: true
end
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end
```

This can be useful if there are a lot of associated records and loading them into memory would be problematic.

You can also get the count of an assocation by using select with a join:

```
authors = Author.select('authors.*, COUNT(books.*) AS authors.number_of_books')
      .left_joins(:books) 
      .order('authors.number_of_books')

# just an example 
authors.map { |a| [a.name, a.number_of_books] }
```

This gives a more accurate number since the value in the counter-cache can be stale.

Comment: `.left_joins` is new in Rails 5. https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/24/support-for-left-outer-joins-in-rails-5.html

Comment: I know how to solve this kind of problem with preloading, and about counter_cache. What I am wondering is -- is there a semantic, drop-in replacement for `to_a.any?`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do exactly that, but you'll need to reload the author object with a new query:

```
author = Author.where(id: author.id).includes(:books).first
```

This loads the child records, as evidenced by:

```
author.books.loaded?
#=> true
```

You can now do `author.books.any?` or even `author.books.map(&:field_name)` and no new query will be run.